# Hackerrank - Is there a way to download all my submissions at once?

Tags: github

I want to upload some of my `Hackerrank` submissions to `GitHub` repo. Can I download these at once or I have to download manually each submission from the [Submission Page](https://www.hackerrank.com/submissions/all)?

Comment: This article implements a scraper to go through hackerrank https://medium.com/hackernoon/scrapping-your-hackerrank-com-submissions-with-python-d409bdf516bb

Answer (score 1):

There is no official way to get your code from hackerrank, but you can use web scrapers.
Here is an implementation of it https://github.com/hearsid/hackerrank-scraper.